# What is "дембельский аккорд"?

Tags: значения

Why is it called so? Дембель is a soldier that ends his service soon. Why аккорд?

Looks like it is some kind of an action before service ends. Does any action qualifies for the "chord"? Does it imply some kind of joke? (E.g. painting horses into zebras or something like that, which is found out after that person(s) leave the army).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Аккордная работа](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/473385/%D0%90%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4) — разовая работа, оплачиваемая по её полному выполнению.

[Де́мбельский акко́рд](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4) — объём разовых работ, выполняемый по приказу командования военнослужащими срочной службы (как правило в последние один-два месяца перед увольнением в запас), условия выполнения которого неформально связаны с датой их предстоящего увольнения и мотивируются последней.

Comment: Wow! I thought аккорд has something to do with musical term, like "ending chord" of some kind. Didn't know about economic term.